# Form validation before the submission and at time of the data entry

Tags: forms, reactjs, validation, jsx

I started to study React and wanted to create the form  for multiple inputs, where I can check the validation of the data at the time of input and again before submitting of the form.
The conditions to submit: all fields are mandatory and the data is valid.

Currently, if user enters invalid data in input field, error text is displayed near the same field. And if user clicked button "submit" on the form with empty fields, error text is also displayed.

But I can't really work it out, how should I do the validation before the submission of the form in my example: : the form has the input field with an error or not.

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'

const ErrorOutput = props => {
  let name = props.name
  let inputValue = props.case
  let submit = props.submit
  console.log(props.submit)
  if (name === 'firstName') {
    if (!inputValue.match(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/) && inputValue.length > 0) {
        return <span>Letters only</span>
      } else if (submit && inputValue.length === 0) {
        return <span>Required</span>
      }
    return <span></span>
  }
  if (name === 'telNo') {
    if(!inputValue.match(/^[0-9]+$/) && inputValue.length > 0) {
        return <span>Numbers only</span>
      } else if (submit && inputValue.length === 0) {
        return <span>Required</span>
      }
    return <span></span>
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      firstName: '',
      telNo: '',
      submit: false
    }
  }

  handleSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    let submit = true
    this.setState ({submit: submit})
    // ... Validation
  }

  handleValidation(e) {    
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value 
    })  
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
        <div>
          <label>
            First name:
          </label>
          <input
            type='text'
            name ='firstName'
            value = {this.state.firstName}
            onChange = {this.handleValidation.bind(this)}
          />
          <ErrorOutput case={this.state.firstName} name={'firstName'} submit = {this.state.submit} />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>
            Phone number:
          </label>
          <input
            type='tel'
            name ='telNo'
            value = {this.state.telNo}
            onChange = {this.handleValidation.bind(this)}
          />
          <ErrorOutput case={this.state.telNo} name={'telNo'} submit = {this.state.submit} />
        </div>
        <button>
          Submit
        </button> 
      </form>
    )
  }
}

render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)    
    this.state = {
        form:{
            firstName: {
              value: '',
              validation: {
                required: true
              },
              valid: false,
              touched: false
            },
            telNo: {
              value: '',
              validation: {
                required: true
              },
              valid: false,
              touched: false
            }
         },
         formIsValid:false
      }
    }
    checkValidity(value, rules) {
        let isValid = true;

        if (rules.required) {
          isValid = value.trim() !== '' && isValid;
        }
        return isValid;
      }

    handleValidation = (event) => {
        let fieldName = event.target.name;
        let fieldValue = event.target.value;
        const updatedCategoryForm = {
          ...this.state.form
        };
        const updatedFormElement = {
          ...updatedCategoryForm[fieldName]
        };
        updatedFormElement.touched = true;
        updatedFormElement.value = fieldValue;
        updatedFormElement.valid = this.checkValidity(updatedFormElement.value, updatedFormElement.validation);
        if (!updatedFormElement.valid && updatedFormElement.validation ) {
          updatedFormElement.elementValidation = "Invalid";
        } else {
          updatedFormElement.elementValidation = "";
        }
        updatedCategoryForm[fieldName] = updatedFormElement;

        let formIsValid = true;
        for (let inputIdentifier in updatedCategoryForm) {
          formIsValid = updatedCategoryForm[inputIdentifier].valid && formIsValid;
        }
        this.setState({ form: updatedCategoryForm, formIsValid: true });
      }
```

Based on the value of `formIsValid` field disable submit button

Answer (score 0):

the following code is an example of adding data via form and form validation prior to the submit. More validations can be added.

```
class Form extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  name: '',
  age: '',
  email: '',
  errorName: '',
  errorAge: '',
  errroMail: '',
  dataValue: false
};
this.getName = this.getName.bind(this);
this.getAge = this.getAge.bind(this);
this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
this.postDatainDisplay = this.postDatainDisplay.bind(this);
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (this.props.name !== nextProps.name) {
        this.setState({ dataValue: true });
    }
}
postDatainDisplay(dataObj) {
    this.props.postData(dataObj);
}
getName(event) {
    const { name, age } = this.state;
    this.setState({ errorName: '' });
    this.setState({ name: event });
}
getAge(event) {
   const { age } = this.state;
   this.setState({ errorAge: '' });
   this.setState({ age: event });
}
handleSubmit() {
const { name, age } = this.state;
//add more validation here 
if (name === '') {

  this.setState({ errorName: 'name cannot be blank', dataValue: false 
});

} else if (age === '') {

  this.setState({ errorAge: 'Age cannot be blank', dataValue: false });
} else
{     this.setState({ data: { name, age } }, () => {
      this.props.sendData(this.state.data);
}
render() {
const { name, age } = this.props;
return (
  <div className="container">
    <form>
      name:<input
        type="text"
        onChange={event => {
          this.getName(event.target.value);
        }}
      />
      {this.state.errorName}
      <br />
      <br />
      age:{' '}
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={event => {
          this.getAge(event.target.value);
        }}
      />
      {this.state.errorAge}
      <br />
      <br />
       <input type="button" onClick={this.handleSubmit} value="Submit" 
       />
    </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Yes, but in this example you can check validation only after submitting. But I want to create a form where I can check the validation at the time of the data entry and after click button 'submit' without having to repeat the validation rules in handleChange and handleSubmit